# Inputs which return optimal output of a blackbox model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, nonlinear-regression, fitting

I am currently working on a problem and now got stuck to implement one of it's steps. This is a simple attempt to explain what I am currently facing, which is something that I am aiming to implement in my regression simulation in python.

Let's say that I fit a non-linear model to my data. Now, I want to find the combination of inputs within a specified range that returns the the highest outcome. When I am using a quadratic function or only a few inputs, this task is quite simple. However, the problem comes when trying to apply the same logic for more complex models. Supposing that I have 9 variables as inputs, I will have to test all possible combinations and that would be computationally unfeasible by doing it with meshgrid if you want to cover a range with a several intervals in between.

So, here it comes my question, is there such a way to avoid having to go through this computationally costly process in order to achieve the combinations of inputs defined in a given range that return the optimal output?

Comment: The modeling itself should have given a single result with the highest outcome, and for each of the 9 inputs you can individually find that input's value at that highest point and the two values on each side of that highest point's value. That makes the grid search size 9 inputs times 3 values. Basically, my thinking is to limit the grid search ranges to the portion of the model with the highest output and subdivide those ranges for grid search. That might work as a first cut at the problem, with analysis of those results used to decide any future grid search work. That's how I would start.